# Медиа запрос для Ipad и Ipad Pro

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Проблема с медиа запросами. Есть медиа запросы:

**Ipad**:

`@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 768px)`

**Ipad Pro**:

`@media only screen and (min-device-width: 767px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)`

Получается, что второй запрос отображается и на Ipad и соответственно мне мешает. Не могу понять почему он вообще работает на Ipad если разрешения разные. Объясните пожалуйста.

Чем отличаются эти `media`-запросы:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px)

@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 992px) 

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 769px)
```

Comment: Помогло предложенное решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя пересечение в максимальных и минимальных значениях.

**Ipad:**

```
max-device-width: 768px
```

**Ipad Pro:**

```
min-device-width: 767px
```

Увеличь данной значение на `1-2px`.

### Разница в `media`-запросах:

`only` игнорирует старые версии браузеров, то есть `media`-запрос не будет выполнен в старой версии браузера.

`screen` - [тип устройства](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media) на котором будет выводится ваш контент, для данного типа соответствуют цифровые устройства такие как мониторы, и мобильные экраны.

На данный момент лучшей практикой для современных устройств является использование `media`-запросов типа:

```
@media only screen and (max/min-width: value)
```